# How many ways are there to place two mutually non-attacking kings on a chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics

I started by counting the 3 cases: when a king is in a corner, a king is on a border, and the king on anywhere else. If the king is in a corner, then there are 4*60 ways. If a king is on a border, then there are 24*60 ways. If placed anywhere else, there are 36*27 ways. Am I correct?

Comment: Are the kings distinguishable? IOW, if I interchange them, do I get the same or a different placement?

Comment: it the kings are distinct, this question becomes more harder.

Comment: @Kiran No it doesn't get much harder; you would just multiply by two the answer for indistinguishable kings.

Comment: Swapping the kings doesn't get a new placement.

Comment: @GerardL. How about board rotations or mirroring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not correct.

There are $64$ squares on a chess board; a king will occupy one of these and attack $3$ squares from a corner, $5$ squares from a plain edge and $8$ squares away from the edge. Kings are distinct and the board is oriented.

Placing the black king first:

- if it is on one of the $4$ corner squares, you are correct that there are $60$ squares not attacked available for the white king.
- if the black king is on one of the $24$ non-corner edge squares, there are only $58$ squares not attacked available for the white king.
- if the black king is on one of the $36$ non-border squares, there are $55$ squares not attacked available for the white king.

The total options for placement then are $4\cdot 60 + 24\cdot 58 + 36\cdot 55 =3612$

If you want to focus on the squares used, rather than the distinct king placements, there are $3612/2 = 1806$ two-square selections available, each leading to two of the above solutions by choosing which king goes in which square.

Comment: your answer assumes kings are identical?

Comment: No, the kings are distinct. This is chess.

Comment: if so, the statement "if it is on one of the 4 corner squares, you are correct that there are 60 squares not attacked available for the white king" is wrong i believe. we many need to use inclusion exclusion here. 4*60 overcounts

Comment: Another point, if one king is in corner, another king can occur in 58 positions only because the kings must be in non-attacking positions? (3 positions can be attacked by the king in the corner)

Comment: okie, got the point. it does not over count as well. i think you are right.